styled-components are not loaded the first time, reloading the page fix it
I have a website with mixed usage of wordpress and react.
The react part has a big usage of styled-components.
Usually the react part is reachable with a normal <a href> link from the wordpress part
The first time when the react page is rendered (coming from wordpress part) styled components is not loaded. If I reload the page it's all ok
I'm attaching the screenshots (first case not loaded, second one yes)


"styled-components": "^6.1.13" (upgraded from 4.x)
"react": "16.8.6"
"babel-plugin-styled-components": "2.1.4"

server nginx
I've tried to upgrade styled components, use incognito mode... no luck
UPDATE:
Today I noticed that the "data-styled-version" is present twice
<style data-styled="active" data-styled-version="6.1.11"></style>
<style data-styled="active" data-styled-version="6.1.13"></style>

When I reload the second row become the first and then the css works. With the above order they doesn't work.
I don't know why I have double entries

this issue might be a result of 3 things. css loading race condition, ssr or hydration mismatch, or cache issues. also, are you sure there are no conflicting styles?

Do you have some suggestions on where to look on this things?

are you using client side rendering or server side rendering?

client side rendering

make sure the  of your document is properly managing the injection of styles created by styled-components. for example, your react entry file must reference to your global style component before referencing other components. `import { createGlobalStyle } from 'styled-components';
const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle  // Your global styles here;
function App() {
return (
<>

{/* Your components here */}
</>
);
}`

I don't use createGlobalStyle, and I have another project with identical boilerplate (different dependencies) which is working without it.
See the update from the post

Solved
It was a third part library injected with google tag manager
(https://www.customerly.io/ in order to solve instead of inject its  tag in the head of html I've injected manually its code in the main react/javascript code)
